# Typescript - Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following simple code for practicing rxJS in Typescript.

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import {
    Observable, Subject, asapScheduler, pipe, of, from,
    interval, merge, fromEvent, SubscriptionLike, PartialObserver
} from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';

function getUserId() {
    return from<Promise<{userId: number}>>(
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(r => r.json())
    )
    .pipe(map(v => v.userId))
    .subscribe(console.log);
}

getUserId();
```

Why does the command prompt throws an error?

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\typescript>ts-node from.ts

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:423

    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
from.ts:12:22 - error TS2339: Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'unknown'
.

12     .pipe(map(v => v.userId))
                        ~~~~~~
...
```

i thought the code should work because the userId is already defined in `return from<Promise<{userId: number}>>{...`

VScode also gives me the error message related with the ***userId***
`Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please try below.

Replace

```
v.userId
```

To

```
v['userId']
```

Comment: Thanks for ur advice Raj. Just check the code working well. Can i ask one more question. What's difference between v.userId and v['userId']?

Comment: @Daino I don't know the fact behind this but I have faced this many times.

Comment: @Daino There's no difference, `v['userId']` just doesn't get type checked. So, it's more of a workaround.